# UTF8 data in JSON can't save as NSString properly

Tags: iphone, json, utf-8, nsstring

I've tried to get some data which contains utf-8 characters from iOS, ended up failing : (

1. JSON data come from Rails app.

   `render :json => @users`

   snippet shows below:
     `{"likes_num":554,"name":"\u62c9\u7f8e\u4eb2\u5386\u8bb0\u00a0","remote_id":63573783,"remote_identifier":"douban"}`
2. Used both `NSJSONSerialization` and `SBJson` with failures. And it seems utf-8 string are modified as `name = "\U62c9\U7f8e\U4eb2\U5386\U8bb0\U00a0";`(Using `NSLog(@"%@", json)`).
3. `NSLog(@"%@", [json objectForKey:@"name"])` just return nothing, leave no log.
4. Save the name as  `NSString *name`, and `NSLog` remains the same, but print description of `name` when debug, the utf-8 sentence appears perfectly.
5. Tried `[name description]`, got nothing either.

Please give me some hints to figure out what really happens to my utf-8 sentence.
Thanks in advanced.

*UPDATE*: Value for other keys works fine, i.e `[json objectForKey:@"remote_identifier"]` gives `douban`, only `@"name"` down for no reason.

Dave

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help from a colleague of mine, i got over this finally. Here is how:

Actually, there are something i haven't mentioned in the question that the value of `name` can sometimes be `null` or `nil`. And with this type of value, the type of this field is set to something related to `KFNull`, and every access of the data risk in sending a `isEqualToString:` to NSNull which doesn't response to that method.

And i still don't understand why `NSLog` failed to print out the non-null data. But i've got a solution to the problem.

```
 NSString *name = [json objectForKey:@"name"];
 if ((CFNull)name == kCFNull)
   name = nil;
 myLabel.text = name;
```

Surprisingly it have no relation with encoding : /

Answer (score 1):

I think you getting this data through some web request(web script)(You have mentioned,you are getting this data from rails APP.)

in my opinion you should check this out.

```
//before below line of code suppose you have done everything like ,you have creating request just encode data using `NSUTF8StringEncoding`


NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

i'd like to tell something about the`NSUTF8StringEncoding:-`
You have to tell `NSString` using which `encoding` can the bytes of the `NSData` be interpreted as a valid string. It won't, however, modify/convert your string between encodings. If the `NSData` object contains a byte sequence which is not valid `UTF-8`, it will simply return nil.

```
 //then follow further steps as you were .....!!!!
 //like try to parse coming response data
```

Comment: you mean if data is not a valid utf-8 byte sequence, the jsonString will be nil?  In my case, jsonString can be extracted from data correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting this from a database? if so it might simply be that your database isn't outputting it as UTF8. I had this problem a long time.

I personally prefer TouchJSON over the two you've tried.

You might try RestKit, it has full support for getting JSON and parsing it as well. It seems more geared for what you are trying.

If your response is JSON you simply use the "parsedBody:" method on the response object from RestKit, and its turned into an NSDictionary for you.

https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I've been using afnetworking for my project heavily and this networking library supports several JSON libs exclude the

Comment: Two you have metioned: ( But I will try that. And the sever side is now built on a SQLite database, all settings remain default.

Comment: I just tried setup a mysql database with everything in 'utf8-unicode-ci', unluckily i still got failed as before.

Comment: Oh wait I remember... I once had this problem, and it was really due to a failed insert into the table, the insert into the table was done with another character set, so the utf8 characters sent to it was actually stored as the utf8 representations.

Comment: I figured that the encoding of workable database for my other projects is `utf8-general-ci`, as this one is set to `utf8-unicode-ci`. i have altered the table encoding to `utf8-general-ci`. Didn't work as expected.